# Make the syntax of the command line parameter match the name of a folder if it looks like it

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I am quite new to bash scripting so i don't know how to proceed with sed or awk or any other bash scripting tool. My issue is:
I am supposed to run a sh script which take one parameter. Due to some particular characteristics, we cannot propose any command line input to verify or modify any typo. 
I would like the word written in parameter, to be corrected by comparing it with the names of subfolders being in a precise folder. And so the subfolder name with the spelling most similar to the parameter, comes to replace the initial parameter. In short if the parameter is well written and therefore looks like 100% as a subfolder name, then ok, otherwise perform the likeness test. Here is the actual bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -o pipefail

if [ -z "${STACK_NAME}" ]; then
    echo "Error: Missing some parameters"
    exit 1
fi

ansible-playbook -vv \
    -e 'ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/bin/env python"' \
    -i inventories/${STACK_NAME}
```

The folder with subfolders look like :

inventories **(main folder)** 
   - docker-stg
   - es-monitoring
   - production
   - development
   - test

So if i enter the command to run the sh script:

```
sh script.sh monitoring
```

Or the command:

```
sh script.sh monit
```

or:

```
sh script.sh esmonit
```

In each case the script should take the parameter and use actually **"es-monitoring"** 
Thank you for your help. best regards

Comment: Your actual script doesn't make use of the arguments at all.

Comment: Why do you use `sh` and `/bin/bash` as shebang?

Comment: @YoussefHarkati : You are referencing a variable _STACK_NAME_, but you never set it, so the `-z` test will be true all the time, unless it is an environment variable set by one of the parent processes.

Comment: The criterion *"most similar to the parameter"* is the most crucial and difficult part. You may need to introduce `"Levenshtein distance"` rather than `regex`.

Comment: What should `sh script.sh es` do? What about `sh script.sh tests`? Or `sh script.sh kubernetes`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your directory names are always different (the easy case!):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 1 ]
then
    echo "ERROR, missing argument."
    echo "       Usage: $0 [arg]"
    exit 1
else
    arg=$1
fi

if [ ! -d *$arg* ]
then
    echo "ERROR: no directory includes that value."
    exit 1
else
    directory=$(find . -type d -name "*$arg*" -prune -print)
    echo "Found a directory: $directory"

    ansible-playbook -vv \
    -e 'ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/bin/env python"' \
    -i inventories/$directory
fi
```

Details:

- the -d test operator verifies if a directory exists by that name (here *$arg*)
- if it does I need it's name.  But if I use `ls` it will also list files that match *$arg*.  So I use a `find` with `-type d` to list only directories.
- `-prune` is used to ensure the find will not recurse in sub-directories.

---

If multiple directories can be present, this version will process each one after the other, in a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# != 1 ]
then
    echo "ERROR, missing argument."
    echo "       Usage: $0 [arg]"
    exit 1
else
    arg=$1
fi

directories=$(find . -type d -name "*$arg*" -prune -print)
if [ -z $directories ]
then
    count=0
else
    count=$(echo $directories | wc -l)
fi

if [ $count == 0 ]
then
    echo "ERROR: no directory includes that value."
    exit 1
else
    echo "Found 1 (or more) directory."

    for DIR in $directories
    do
        #echo $DIR

        ansible-playbook -vv \
        -e 'ansible_python_interpreter="/usr/bin/env python"' \
        -i inventories/$directory
    done
fi
```

- The `-z $directories` verification is to avoid the `wc -l` returning 1 on an empty variable.

Comment: thanks a lot it works. I have one small question if the bash script is on another level, how can we verify if the directory exists ? because i tried some tests but it doesn't work :
if [ ! -d inventories/*${$arg}* ]
then
    echo "ERROR: no directory includes that value."
    exit 1
else
    directory=$(find . -type d -name "inventories/*${$arg}*" -prune -print)
    echo "Found a directory: $directory"

Thank you

Comment: won't this give a syntax error if `*$arg*` expands to multiple directories?

Comment: @jhnc yes you are right. how can i avoid multiple subfolders to come up if they contains the *$arg* pattern ?

Comment: Hi @YoussefHarkati, there are many possibilities.  If it matches multiple directories, what do you want it to do?  Nothing?  Process each one in a loop?  The requirement defines the solution.

Comment: Done, check the second script in the answer

Comment: @Nic3500 Thanks for your reply and yes it is a very good solution in case i have to process the command for each matching directories. In my case i need to proceed the command to the closest match only:  So if there are 2 directories like "es-monit" and "es-monitoring" and if i execute the command "bash test.sh monit", it should prefer the closest match of these 2, which is "es-monit"

Comment: Again, you have to define the exact need.  How do you define "best match" ?  The shortest path found?